# ncurses libraries not found

Tags: c++, solaris

I'm currently trying to install CPM a password management tool on Solaris 11 x86.
After the installation of all the required dependencies I'm stuck at the configuration of CPM.
My current ncurses version is 5.9.

I tried to run this command:

```
root@solaris:~/Downloads/cpm-0.23beta# ./configure --with-ncurses --with-cdk-dir=/usr/local --with-cracklib-dict=/usr/local/share/cracklib/pw_dict
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out  
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/ggrep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/ggrep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
configure: checking libraries
checking for main in -lm... yes
checking for initscr in -lncurses... no
configure: error: can not find the ncurses library
```

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you run ldconfig since installing ncurses?

Comment: @KazDragon - Solaris doesn't have/use ldconfig.

Answer (score 1):

After installing a system library, you should run `ldconfig` as root.  This tool is used to update the system's cache of libraries so that they can be found at link time and in, for example, configure scripts.

Addendum: Solaris version is indeed [crle](http://bwachter.lart.info/solaris/solfaq.html)

Comment: sounds good, I'm don't have a lot of experience on Solaris, can you specify the command? I guess its crle on Solaris..?

Comment: I added the libraries with crle -l <PATHNAME>:<PATHNAME> but I still get the same error..

Comment: Actually, on Solaris there is no ldconfig and you should almost never run crle.   The Solaris recommendation is to use -L and -R flags for linking with any libraries outside the default library path.